# Magento 2.1.9 Paypal Error

Tags: magento2, paypal

Is there a problem with PayPal on Magento 2.1.9?

The error I keep on getting is

> Transaction has been Declined

even if I have everything set up right. I've looked at my PayPal Manager to see the authorized transaction. Everything looks good and approved, but when it comes back to Magento, that's when the error shows up.